# SQL Create Table by OrderID & Product Code between Ship & Return Date w Wkly Revenue

Tags: sql, grouping, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Lo Folks o/

I apologize if I've titled this incorrectly or my terminology may be lacking as I am self-taught in writing SQL data queries; however, I am stuck on how to create one to produce data I need for a weekly rate of return review by product and order based on the orders' ship and return dates.

I have orders' line item detail to the product, qty, price etc. I am needing to group the data by the week start dates between the **"ship" and "return" dates** then calculate that week's revenue based on the line item's total over the number of weeks [and days in that week] the product is out.

I am also not sure if I even have the permissions to create a table, if that is necessary, nor where to begin to create this type of query.

Any help, direction or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks all o/

My raw data looks like

[image: My raw data looks like]

And an excel view of my expected results

[image: And an excel view of my expected results]

Comment: Thanks @GMB for making this easier to view.

Answer (score 1):

hmm ill take a stab - I am assuming you have an ORDERS o table (first image) and a RETURNS r table (second image). Also assuming you have the prodcode in your RETURNS table - maybe something like this:

```
WITH return_details as (  
   SELECT o.main_order, o.maincode, o.itemtotal,
          r.ship_date, r.return_date, 
          DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', r.ship_date) as ship_week,
          datediff(day, r.return_date, r.ship_date) as ship2return
   FROM RETURNS r INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON
   r.orderid = o.main_order AND r.prod_code = o.maincode 
)
SELECT rd.main_order as order_id,
       rd.maincode as prod_code,
       rd.ship_week, 
       SUM(rd.itemtotal) as SUM_REVENUE,
       SUM(rd.ship2return) as SUM_DAYSOUT,
       AVG(rd.ship2return) as AVG_DAYSOUT
FROM return_details rd
GROUP BY order_id, prod_code, ship_week;
```

Comment: Lo there @Chris, this query essentially replicated the line items records with the days calc. 

I am trying to produce the table that is pictured in the third image, listing the start week date for each week an order is out between the ship and return dates. 

Is this possible in snowflake?

Comment: @DataUsurper - how is the start day calculated for the column "Weekstart"?

Comment: @RachelMcGuigan, it was a manually created table to show an example of the desired output.